# Finding permutations of a number using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, algorithm

Is it possible to write a bash script which takes a 4 digit number as an command line argument and produces all permutations of that number with using only pure bash?

Comment: Have you made an attempt to solve it?

Comment: I had tried in C using for string permutations. But curious to do in bash with numbers.

Comment: Please take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.  Here's a function which will do what you're asking.

```
function permutate {
    if [ "${#1}" = 1 ]; then
        echo "${2}${1}"
    else
        for i in $(seq 0 $((${#1}-1)) ); do
            pre="${2}${1:$i:1}"
            seg1="${1:0:$i}"
            seg2="${1:$((i+1))}"
            seg="${seg1}${seg2}"
            permutate "$seg" "$pre"
        done
    fi
}
```

Run it like this:

```
$ permutate 1234
```

It works by using recursion.  Each call to the function takes one character out of the string and passes the remainder to itself recursively.  So if the input is 1234, it gets broken up into a prefix and remaining segment four times like this: `1 234` `2 134` `3 124` `4 123`.  The three character segments then get the same treatment, then the two character segments, and then the recursion stops when the segment is only one character.

Comment: Wow. Thanks dear. Its working . I need to improve my shell logic

Comment: Can we sort the output to (cat)  to another file

Comment: Sure, just use the sort command like so `permutate 1234 | sort >output.txt`

Comment: off topic but asking you, Advance thanks. How to use this bash command in c language function execl() .. the bash command is `ls -lR /path/to/dir/*.jpg | wc -l` i need to use this command in c program. Any help?

Comment: @user3479901, if you use execl you would do this: `execl("/bin/bash", "-c", "ls -lR /path/to/dir/*.jpg | wc -l", NULL)`.  However, if you want to capture the output of the shell command, try using `popen()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Massive abuse of the `shuf` command, which I realise makes it not pure bash:

```
damson$ cat shell-combinations 
#!/bin/bash

R=1000
PERM_OR_COMB=perm 

if [ $PERM_OR_COMB = perm ]; then
    C_RANGE=$#
else
    C_RANGE=$(seq 0 $#)
fi
for C in $C_RANGE; do
    for I in $(seq 1 $R); do
        echo "$(for X in "$@"; do echo "$X"; done | shuf -n $C | paste -s -d' ')"
    done | sort -u
done
damson$ ./shell-combinations 1 2 3 4  
1 2 3 4
1 2 4 3
1 3 2 4
1 3 4 2
1 4 2 3
1 4 3 2
2 1 3 4
2 1 4 3
2 3 1 4
2 3 4 1
2 4 1 3
2 4 3 1
3 1 2 4
3 1 4 2
3 2 1 4
3 2 4 1
3 4 1 2
3 4 2 1
4 1 2 3
4 1 3 2
4 2 1 3
4 2 3 1
4 3 1 2
4 3 2 1
damson$
```

Obviously it's slow and in theory it's not reliable, but depending on your use case and how big `R` is compared to `$#`, it might satisfy your needs. Change `PERM_OR_COMB=perm` to `PERM_OR_COMB=comb` to get all the combinations instead of all the permutations.